# Wagtail draftail paragraph style

Tags: wagtail

I'm looking to add a custom BlockFeature to the wagtail draftail editor that converts to a paragraph tag with a specific class.

```
<p>A normal paragraph</p>
<p class="margin-0">A special paragraph using my custom feature</p>
```

This is my attempt:

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_margin0_feature(features):
    """
    Registering the `margin-0` feature, which uses the `blockquote` Draft.js block type,
    and is stored as HTML with a `<p class="margin-0">` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'margin-0'
    type_ = 'custom'
    tag = 'p'
    classname = "margin-0"

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': '❝',
        'description': 'Paragraph with margin-0',
        # Optionally, we can tell Draftail what element to use when displaying those blocks in the editor.
        'element': 'blockquote',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.BlockFeature(control)
    )

    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, {
        'from_database_format': {'p[margin-0]': BlockElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {
            'block_map': {
                type_: {
                    'element': tag,
                    'props': {
                        'class': 'margin-0',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
```

This saves correctly to the database and generates the correct page markup, however, when I open the page in wagtail admin the draftail editor mistakes it for a normal paragraph.

Looking through the wagtail source I noticed this in html_ruleset.py:

> Look for a rule matching an HTML element with the given name and attribute dict, and return the corresponding result object. If no rule matches, return None.
>   If multiple rules match, the one chosen is undetermined.

Since there is a built in 'p' tag handler, does this make recognising 'p class="margin-0"' impossible?

It would be great to be able to just write the custom class you want on each paragraph in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the ruleset system doesn't currently give precedence to more specific rules, so there's no way to define a rule that supersedes the default `<p>` rule. This is an open feature request: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4527

However, note that the selector `p[margin-0]` is incorrect, as this would match a `<p>` element with a `margin-0` attribute rather than a `class` attribute - it should be `p[class="margin-0"]`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Any update on that feature? I would like to add my own div's with a special class.

Comment: Hey is it possible to add a tag with content in it? Like hit the button and it inserts <p>123</p>